# error con los datetimepicker al pasar a otra pc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, windows, datetime

Al pasar a otra computadora mi programa los datetimepicker en formato de fecha corta salen como '20/09/2017' pero en mi computadora salen como '20/09/17' y la programación esta con este formato así que cuando pongo a buscar o hacer alguna consulta no concuerda nunca la fecha, uso sqlserver y visual studio 2010.

Comment: lo acabo de resolver muchas gracias, supongo que por el sistema los datetimepicker difieren en su formato, he aprendido a usar la propiedad custom format y gracias a ello lo resolví, muchas gracias por contestar rápido a pesar de tu petulancia.Recuerda que esta sección se llama preguntas, si necesitas el signo esta bien , pero el problema se planteo y la zona ya dice preguntas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El control DateTimePicker, si le estableces el valor `Short` a la propiedad `Format`, va a tomar como formato el formato de fecha corta establecido en la configuración regional del equipo.

Puedes forzar que tenga el mismo formato independientemente del equipo y su configuración regional estableciendo la propiedad `Format` como `Custom` y especificando en la propiedad `CustomFormat` el formato a utilizar, por ejemplo `"dd/MM/yy"` para tu caso.

En cualquier caso el formato en el que se muestran las fechas no debería afectar al código de tu aplicación. Las fechas deberías manejarlas en variables de tipo de datos fecha y no como cadenas. Únicamente deberían convertirse a cadenas para mostrarlas al usuario (en pantalla, informes, ....) pero no a la hora de manejarlas en tu código (por ejemplo para filtrar datos).